# Solution to react-navigation Can't find module

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[image]Does React has a solution for this issue. This is really frustrating

none of thee fix workaround work.
this is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "HotelReservation",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.4.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

and class **App**

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen'

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

Anything I should update ?
Is that a react issue or a bug with react-navigation

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `package.json` file, it seems like you do not have the following libraries: `react-native-reanimated`, `react-native-gesture-handler` and `react-native-screens`. If you are using bare React Native project, you need to add these libraries and link those libraries. For versions of React Native 0.60 and higher, these libraries will be automatically linked after you add the above libaries (i.e either use `yarn` or `npm` to add those). However, as you are using React Native 0.59, you need to link the dependencies manually. Refer to this documentation to add and link those dependencies. It also gives you all the details of getting started on React Navigation.